# Web Scraping - recursive calls to links from href, traverse store data

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So, I am creating a web scraper that visits a website, finds all the div with `li elements`.
Then traverses the li's and stores them inside a `text file`.

Now, the website has embedded links within some li also.

So, I need to traverse the links and find the li elements within them and come back to the parent page.
[image: pageStructure]

***My Code is shared below***

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def writeToFile(ul):
    for li in ul:
        with open('path/to/file.txt', 'a+') as f:
            text = li.text
            f.write(text + ',')
            f.close()


def searchElements(url):
    print(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    divs = soup.findAll('div', id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('mntl-sc-block_1-0-'))
    for div in divs:
        ul = div.find("ul")
        if ul is not None:
            ulVariable = ul.findAll('a')
            for b in ulVariable:
                if ulVariable is not None:
                    if b is not None:
                        linkItemsList = list()
                        links = (b.get("href"))
                        linkItemsList.append(links)
                        for link in linkItemsList:
                            searchElements(link)
                            print('link internal data print')
                            writeToFile(ul)
                else:
                    print('link in not none else')
                    writeToFile(ul)
        print('all non link')
        writeToFile(ul)


def main():
    searchElements('https://www.thebalancecareers.com/list-of-information-technology-it-skills-2062410')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not getting the proper logic for the recursive calls. I am getting stuck in the child pages.

So, I would be really appreciative of any help that I receive

Comment: What are you expecting to return? Just links? And only links for initial landing page and first level children? And can you share the start url?

Comment: and what is the problem ? create two function - first to load and search on main page, second to load and search on child page. Inside first function you will find urls and use second function to find elements on child page.

Comment: @QHarr I want to return the Text inside the `li` tags. Also, there are second level, third level children also. I updated the code with the URL
@furas The problem is, once i start the recursive function, I cannot come out of the function calls. The program starts to run in loops, always writing the gathered data in a series like, 2, 4, 6, 8.

Comment: @QHarr the code is complete. you could see for yourself. And help me out. Sorry, I am not being able to explain what exactly I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main reason why your code gets stuck is because some web page links to page your code already visited; this create an infinite loop with the recursive call hanging forever.

To avoid this you need to keep track of the visited links; you can do this with a list as I did in the code below.

The code below reaches the end of the search, but in order to do it, there're some caveats to care about:

1. some pages link to external links which are broken; this's why I put a `try, except` clause (otherwise: errors...)
2. some text (at least one, as far as I could check) has special character in it -'\u200b'- which annoys file write, that's why I changed open to codecs.open with encoding in order to be able to manage it.
3. At least one link redirects to https://web.archive.org/... (s. code below) so I used regular expression to change it back to www.thebalancecareers.com/. If this is not what you intend to do with those links, you have to adapt the code.
4. Finally, I commented the last `writeToFile(ul)` since it was writing None to the file causing errors.

I hope this helps.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
import re

def writeToFile(ul):
    for li in ul:
        # codecs.open with encoding can manage some spacial characters in
        # you text such as '\u200b' 
        with codecs.open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='a+') as f:
            text = li.text
            f.write(text + ',')
            f.close()

def searchElements(url, visitedurls):
    visitedurls.append(url)
    print(url)
    # Uncomment the following line to see all link visited by searchElements
    # print(visitedurls)

    # Some external links referenced by www.thebalancecareers.com
    # don't exist anymore or are forbidden
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except (urllib.error.HTTPError, urllib.error.URLError):
        return

    html = response.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    divs = soup.findAll('div', id=lambda x: x and x.startswith('mntl-sc-block_1-0-'))
    for div in divs:
        ul = div.find("ul")
        if ul is not None:
            ulVariable = ul.findAll('a')
            for b in ulVariable:
                if ulVariable is not None:
                    if b is not None:
                        linkItemsList = list()
                        links = (b.get("href"))
                        linkItemsList.append(links)
                        for link in linkItemsList:
                            # Get rid of this kind of link:
                            # https://web.archive.org/web/20180425012458/https:/www.thebalancecareers.com/....
                            link = re.sub(r'https://web.archive.org/(.*)/https:', 'https:/', link)
                            if link in visitedurls:
                                print('%s already traversed' % link)
                                return
                            else:
                                searchElements(link, visitedurls)
                                print('link internal data print')
                                writeToFile(ul)
                else:
                    print('link in not none else')
                    writeToFile(ul)
        print('all non link')

        # Commented: this would try to write None
        # resulting in an error
        #writeToFile(ul)

def main():
    visitedurls = []
    searchElements('https://www.thebalancecareers.com/list-of-information-technology-it-skills-2062410', visitedurls)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. We knew that we were stuck in the recursive calls but didn't know how to handle it.
You fix worked like a charm